# Notification in JellyBean - add action isn't work

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, broadcast, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Need some help with building an Jelly Bean notification with custom button (using addAction).
The problem is, that i cannot just make it working.
Basically, i want to build notification with following parameters: on notification click it must bring one of my activities up, on button click - play-pause player, which is running, when notification is shown.
My code is: 
Receiver:

```
private BroadcastReceiver onNotification = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("NOTIFICATION", "Received broadcast");
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        int state = extras.getInt("state");
        if (state == 1) {
            playPauseMethod();
        }

    }

};
```

In onCreate method of activity i've added:

```
IntentFilter notif_iff = new IntentFilter(
                    MainService.NOTIF_BROADCAST);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(
                    onNotification, notif_iff);
```

Code in MainService is following:

```
public static final String ACTION = "com.formatbce.mdrive.action.UPDATE_UI";
public static final String NOTIF_BROADCAST = "com.formatbce.mdrive.action.NOTIF_BRD";
Intent in = new Intent(ACTION);
Intent notifInt = new Intent(NOTIF_BROADCAST);
private NotificationManager mNM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

private void showNotification(final int statusBarIconID,
        final int bigIconID, final int ppIconID, final String contentTitle,
        final String contentText, final boolean showIconOnly) {
    PendingIntent layoutIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, MediaFragmentActivity.class), 0);

        int state = 1;
        notifInt.setAction("blabla");
        notifInt.putExtra("state", state);
        PendingIntent mIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                getApplicationContext(), 0, notifInt,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle(contentTitle).setContentText(contentText)
        .setSmallIcon(bigIconID).setContentIntent(layoutIntent)
        .addAction(ppIconID, null, mIntent)
        .build();
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
            mNM.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification);
}
```

So, when i calling showNotification() method, notification is shown, and click in it's body is working well. But when i'm clicking a button, setted with addAction, nothing changes... I mean, even that line in onReceive() isn't work:

```
Log.d("NOTIFICATION", "Received broadcast");
```

What can be wrong here? I read manuals in huge amount, but can't get it. Can somebody explain, how to get it working?
Thank you!

P.S. When i changing addAction PendingIntent to getActivity, it works fine, btw...

Comment: Somebody? Please tell me at least, is there problem in my understanding of that feature, or nobody actually knows an answer? :(

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're stuck with here is that the BroadcastReceiver isn't setup correctly. I'd actually suggest using a Service instead of a BroadcastReceiver, just due to latency of the BroadcastReceiver (at the same time, it should happen soon enough that it's likely not a big deal).

Do you have the BroadcastReceiver setup correctly in your Manifest?

Are you able to create an activity that just invokes the BroadcastReceiver (to verify that it's working correctly)?

Comment: Thanks for answer. although this project is already forgotten, i will try to pick it up on weekend.

Comment: I'd say to put the broadcast receiver in its own class and register it in the manifest, then try performing the action. I'm not sure how (if) the inlined broadcast receiver declaration is registered with the system.

Comment: Well, have to say, that in usual cases inline receiver works like a charm. However, as i said, i'll tryt this at weekend, thanx.